# What is the lambda equivalent of this Linq query?

Tags: linq, lambda

What is the equivalent lambda syntax to this linq query?

```
Dim query = From t In _rdsqlconn.Tags Where t.TagWord = tag 
   Join p In _rdsqlconn.Posts On t.PostId Equals p.PostId Order By p.PostDatePublished 
   Descending Select p Where p.PostIsPublished = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a join, like so:

```
_rdsqlconn.Tags
    .Where(t => t.TagWord == tag)
    .Join(_rdsqlconn.Posts, t => t.PostId, p => p.PostId, (t, p) => p)
    .Where(p => p.PostIsPublished == true)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostDatePublished)
```

but what you **want** to do is properly map your tables and relationships in the LINQ-to-SQL designer, and then you can use

```
_rdsqlconn.Posts.Where(p => p.PostIsPublished && p.Tags.Any(t => t.TagWord == tag))
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.PostDatePublished)
```

If you have a foreign key between Posts and Tags in your database then you will be able to do this. It's much cleaner code, and removes the unnecessarily Join operator.